# How can I add a label to f.select on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've been trying to add a label for the following code

```
<%= f.select :platform, Idea::PLATFORM_PICKING%>
```

but it keeps ignoring it,so I researched why this is happen and it turns out that it's because f.select isn't simple_form method, so is there another way I can add label to it?

Comment: Simple form? Try: `f.input :platform, collection: Idea::PLATFORM_PICKINGS, as: :select`

Answer (score 3):

Use label for forms:

```
<%= f.label :platform%>
```

check the [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html)